# Clone Div to Inside other Div

Tags: php, jquery, html, clone

I want to clone a div to another div in jQuery
how can i do it?

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="applicationManualInput last" >
      <input type="text" name="name[]"  required placeholder="Name" id="name">
    </div>
<div class="formInputReplace"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="check()">
```

My jQuery is

```
var applicationClone = $('.applicationManualInput last').clone().val('');

    // now re-insert it after the .last element
     applicationClone.prependTo('.formInputReplace');

    // now remove all .last classes
    $('.applicationManualInput').removeClass('last');

    // and add it to the last element
    $('.applicationManuelInput').last().addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

it not works beacuse `applicationManualInput` class and `last` class in same div

```
var applicationClone = $('.applicationManualInput last').clone().val('');
```

May be your scenario

```
$('.applicationManualInput.last')
```

Comment: i want to clone that div to inside the second div

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

**JQuery:**

```
$(".applicationManualInput").clone().appendTo($(".formInputReplace"));
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NHXB/)

Comment: And how to clean the input inside the div?

Comment: `$('.formInputReplace input').val("")`

Comment: But with that cicle? clone clean paste

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#from").clone().appendTo($("#to"));
```